# Logic for parsing names

Tags: algorithm, logic

I am wanting to solve this problem, but am kind of unsure how to correctly structure the logic for doing this. I am given a list of user names and I am told to find an extracted name for that. So, for example, I'll see a list of user names such as this:

```
jason
dooley
smith
rob.smith
kristi.bailey
kristi.betty.bailey
kristi.b.bailey
robertvolk
robvolk
k.b.dula
kristidula
kristibettydula
kristibdula
kdula
kbdula
alexanderson
caesardv
joseluis.lopez
jbpritzker
jean-luc.vey
dvandewal
malami
jgarciathome
christophertroethlisberger
```

How can I then turn each user name into an extracted name? The only parameter I am given is that every user name is guaranteed to have at least a partial person's name.

So for example, kristi.bailey would be turned into "Kristi Bailey"
alexanderson would be turned into "Alex Anderson"

So, the pattern I see is that, if I see a period I will turn that into two strings (possibly a first and last name). If I see three periods then it will be first, middle. The problem I am having trouble finding the logic for is when the name is just clumped up together like alexanderson or jgarciathome. How can I turn that into an extracted name? I was thinking of doing something like if I see 2 consonants and a vowel in a row I would separate the names, but I don't think that'll work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you please post the expected output?

Comment: I was not given the output for this problem. I Suspect there may not be an answer that would solve every problem like this. As there may just be usernames that are impossible to tell. I am trying to figure out the best way to do this though.

Comment: do you have a dictionary to refer to for "alexanderson" and "jgarciathome"?

Comment: It can't be done. Look at your list: caesardv, Caesar is first name, but you can't make much sense of DV. jason, smith and malami are first name only. Do it manually, or post a job to online contractor.

Comment: Should "alexanderson" resolve to "Alex Anderson" or "Alexander Son" or maybe even "Alexa N Derson"? Is "kristidula" "Kris Tidula" or "Kristi Dula"? Many of your examples are ambiguous. Perhaps a precise definition of what an "extracted name" is might be of use...

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a string.StartsWith method and a string.EndsWith method and determine the maximum overlap on each.  As long as it's more than 2 characters, call that the common name.  Sort them into buckets based on the common name.  It's a naive implementation, but it that's where I'd start.

Example:

```
string name1 = "kristi.bailey";
string name2 = "kristi.betty.bailey";

// We've got a 6 character overlap for first name:
name2.StartsWith(name1.Substring(0,6)) // this is true

// We've got a 6 character overlap for last name:
name2.EndsWith(name1.Substring(7)) // this is true
```

HTH!

Comment: Sort of confused by what you mean by the starts with and ends with. Could you give an example of it?

Comment: Like that.  The maximal index values can be determined algorithmically.

Comment: I've just found out that with this problem you can not associate any of the names with any previous names found. Any other ideas how you would solve this?